# Question about homomorphism and cosets of kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $K : G \to G'$ be a group homomorphism

Show that If order of $G$ is finite, then order of $K[G]$ is finite and is a divisor of order of $G$.

My professor used an one-to-one correspondence between $K[G]$ and kernel of $G$

ans therefore order of $K[G]$ = order of $G$ divided by order of kernel of $G$.

I don't understand why there is one-to-one relationship and it seems to me that order of $K[G]$ is equal to number of left cosets of kernel of $G$

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Have you seen the Lagrange property that says that the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group in the finite case ?

Comment: What makes you say that the order of $K[G]$ is equal to the number of left cosets of $\ker (K)$?

Comment: yes yes to both of you

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you know about the problem, in order to try and clear up exactly what's confusing you. So, you're OK with the fact that he showed that the size of $K(G)$ is the same as the number of left cosets of the kernal of $K$?

Comment: No, that's what I don't really understand. why size of K(G) is the same as number of left cosets of the kernel of K

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955320/g-textorder-of-image-of-f-h.

Answer (score 1):

By the first isomorphism theorem, $K(G)\simeq G/\text{ker } K$. Then $|G/\text{ker }K|=|G|/|\text{ker }K|$ which is a divisor of $G$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem.

Comment: Hmm, Using the first isomorphism theorem indeed makes this question easy!. But, I would like to know nature of this proof, why they must be equal.

Comment: Oh shall we assume that there is onto mapping ?

Comment: By definition, every function is an onto mapping to its image. In this case, $K\colon G\to K(G)$ is onto.

Answer (score 0):

Two elements of $G$ have the same image under $K$ iff they are in the same coset of $\ker K$.

In other words, the inverse image of an element of the image of $f$ (also called a *fiber* of $f$) is a coset of $\ker K$. The number of fibers is clearly the size of the image of $f$.

Since every element of $G$ is in exactly one fiber of $f$, we get the result.

Comment: Adapted from http://math.stackexchange.com/a/955358/589.